# REST API with koa2. Common prefix for several routers

Tags: koa, koa-router, koa2

I have two entities, users and employees. So I want CRUD for both in different endpoints, but both of them will be mounted under "api", so I can define api_v1, api_v2 and so on.
The endpoints would be something like:

```
get api/users
put api/users/12
delete api/users/12
get api/employees
....
```

I can't get "api" prefix for both of my routes. Can't get it working with koa-mount.

***My files:***

**server.js**

```
// Dependencies
import Koa from 'koa'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import logger from 'koa-logger'
// import parser from 'koa-bodyparser';
import convert from 'koa-convert'
import serve from 'koa-static'
import Router from 'koa-router'
import session from 'koa-generic-session'
import mount from 'koa-mount'

// A seperate file with my routes.
import routingUsers from './users'
import routingEmployees from './employees'

// config
const config = require("./config/config")

// connect to the database
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.url)
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error)

// Creates the application.
const app = new Koa()
// how to use koa-mount to make this work? Arghhhhh!
// const api = new Koa();
// api.use(convert(mount ('/api', app)))

// trust proxy
app.proxy = true
// sessions
app.keys = ['your-session-secret']


// Applies all routes to the router.
const user = routingUsers(Router())
const employee = routingEmployees(Router())

app
  .use(logger()) // log requests, should be at the beginning
  .use(user.routes()) // asign routes
  .use(employee.routes()) // asign routes
  .use(user.allowedMethods())
  .use(employee.allowedMethods())
  .use(convert(session())) // session not needed for an API??????
  .use(convert(serve(__dirname + '/public')))   // for static files like images


// Start the application.
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started 3000'))
export default app
```

**users.js** *(employees.js is the same)*.

```
// Export a function that takes the router
export default router => {
  // Set a prefix of our api, in this case locations
  const api = 'users'
  router.prefix(`/${api}`);

  // GET to all locations.
  router.get('/',  (ctx, next) =>
      ctx.body = 'hello users');
    // ctx.body = await Location.find());
  // POST a new location.
  router.post('/', async (ctx, next) =>
    ctx.body = await new Location(ctx.request.body).save());
  // Routes to /locations/id.
  router.get('/:id', async (ctx, next) =>
    ctx.body = await Location.findById(ctx.params.id));
  // PUT to a single location.
  router.put('/:id', async (ctx, next) =>
    ctx.body = await Location.findByIdAndUpdate(ctx.params.id, ctx.body));
  // DELETE to a single location.
  router.delete('/:id', async (ctx, next) =>
    ctx.body = await Location.findByIdAndRemove(ctx.params.id));

  return router;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've sent another parameter to the routers modules, so I used router prefix:

```
// Applies all routes to the router.
const user = routingUsers(Router(), 'api/users/')
const employee = routingEmployees(Router(), 'api/employees/')
```

Users would be:

```
export default (router, prefix) => {
  // Set a prefix of our api, in this case locations
  // const api = 'users'
  router.prefix(`/${prefix}`);
 ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following solution:

```
import Router from 'koa-router';

const router = new Router()
  .get('/', function(ctx) {
    ctx.body = 'Index';
  });


const apiRouter = new Router({
  prefix: '/api'
})
  .get('/templates', Templates.index)
  .post('/templates', Templates.store)
  .put('/templates', Templates.update)
  .get('/lists', Lists.index);


router.use(apiRouter.routes());
```